# Can't connect to steam

Tags: ubuntu, internet, steam

I've just installed Steam on my computer, created a Steam account and tried clicking on the steam icon to load it.  It gave me the following error and then shuts down:

[image]

If I type `steam` in the terminal, it gives me all this:

```
oshirowanen@home-desktop:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
unlinked 0 orphaned pipes
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
[1012/132155:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(646)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 256x256, total string texture memory is 311.30 KB

(steam:3710): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: g_simple_async_result_complete() called from wrong context!

(steam:3710): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: g_simple_async_result_complete() called from wrong context!

(steam:3710): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: g_simple_async_result_complete() called from wrong context!
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
`menu_proxy_module_load': /home/oshirowanen/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load

(steam:3710): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)

roaming config store loaded successfully - 0 bytes.
Adding license for package 0
Generating new string page texture 4: 128x256, total string texture memory is 442.37 KB
Generating new string page texture 5: 512x256, total string texture memory is 966.66 KB
Generating new string page texture 6: 24x256, total string texture memory is 991.23 KB
unlinked 2 orphaned pipes
CAsyncIOManager: 0 threads terminating.  0 reads, 0 writes, 0 deferrals.
CAsyncIOManager: 522 single object sleeps, 0 multi object sleeps
CAsyncIOManager: 0 single object alertable sleeps, 1 multi object alertable sleeps
[2013-10-12 13:21:54] Startup - updater built Jun  6 2013 13:48:29
[2013-10-12 13:21:54] Verifying installation...
[2013-10-12 13:21:54] Verification complete
Shutting down. . .
[2013-10-12 13:22:05] Shutdown
```

Anyone know why I can't load steam?  My internet connection is working obviously, as I wouldn't be able to type all this if I had an internet connection issue.

I've tried reinstalling it many times, but still get the same issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a terminal:

```
steam --reset
```

This will provide a clean install for the client, but leave all your games untouched.

Be aware that although this will "fix" your connection issue, it's akin to buying a new car to fix a flat tire. There is probably a simpler and more elegant solution, but I wasn't able to find one when I had this problem.